# Can a Nazir cut his hair with shears (gezaz)?

Tags: hair, nozir

Can a Nazir cut his hair with shears (gezaz)?

[Numbers 6:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says not to put a razor (tahar) on the head. But there is another word for shears (gezaz) which seems like scissors and scissors don't have to be placed on the head.

gezaz - https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1494.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is forbidden for a nazir to cut his hair completely no matter what tool he uses.** The Rambam writes (MT [Nazir 5:11-12](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/983589/jewish/Nezirut-Chapter-5.htm))

> When a nazirite cuts off one hair, whether using a razor or a scissor,
> he is liable for lashes, provided he cuts it from its roots as a razor
> would. Similarly, if he pulls out [a hair] by hand, he is liable for
> lashes. [...] If he left enough of [the hair] so that it could be bent
> over for its tip to touch its root, he does not receive lashes,
> because [cutting in this manner] is not [equivalent to shaving it]
> with a razor.

(see also [footnote 28](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/983589/jewish/Nezirut-Chapter-5.htm#footnote28a983589))

It is theoretically possible to shave without a tool or one's hand but with a cream, see 5:12

> If a person applied a potion that removed hair to his head and in this
> way, removed his hair, he is not liable for lashes. He is, however,
> nullifying the observance of a positive commandment, as [Numbers 6:5]
> states: "He shall let the mane of the hair of his head grow."

Comment: I meant can a Nazir cut his hair if he keeps it long.

Comment: No it is forbidden as [the verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.6.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says "the hair of his head should be left to grow untrimmed". The discussion in the Rambam is what will be the punishment for cutting his hair with what tool - but there is no question it is forbidden for a nazir to cut his hair. See for instance pictures of a recent Nazir [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cohen_(rabbi)) and [here](http://www.ravkooktorah.org/NASO63.htm)

Comment: I think that the question might still stand, assuming that nezirut in our days is different from what it would be in the Mikdash